# Working with sums in R

Tags: r, sum

How does one work with sums in R? I can't seem to find an easy way to calculate sums \sum_{i=m}^n a_i. There are three things to decide here; where summation starts, where it ends, and what elements are to be summed.

I have a data frame df and I would like to calculate sum_{i=1}^{n-3} df$col[i]*df$col[i+3], col being a column of length 1000 in df, i.e. n=1000... How can I do this? I've found one very cumbersome way of doing it, namely

```
new = NULL

for (n in 1:997)
{ new = df$col[n]*df$col[n+3] }

sum(new)
```

That's a stupid way of doing it, so how do it in a more "natural" way? Yes, I'm sure this precise question has been asked but I didn't know how to narrow down my searches. "R+sum+why dont programmers think like mathematicians", maybe ;) Anyway, hints or links to tutorials for R beginners would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: subset the object being summed: \sum_{i=m}^n a_i = `sum(a[m:n])`

Comment: In your example, "new" is already a function in R so should not be used as a variable name. There's a general preference for using `<-` for assignments instead of `=`.  And in your loop, you've overwriting the value of new in each iteration, so the `sum(new)` just returns the last of the 997 values, not a sum (the answers below do yield sums).

Comment: @SamFirke I don't follow. The above creates a new variable with the summands, and sum(new) sums those summands, as needed. It doesn't return the 997th value.

Comment: The loop is not adding the summands onto the `new` vector, it's rewriting it with a new number each time.  If the line were `{ new = c(new, df$col[n]*df$col[n+3]) }` then it would concatenate each new summand onto the existing vector.  With the sample vector `df <- data.frame(col = 1:1000)`, I get 332332004 from the answers but 997000 from running your code.

Comment: @SamFirke I don't know. I tried it with df = c(1:8) and it works as I have described; summands are "logged" into new, then sum(new) sums those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
sum(df$col[1:997] * df$col[4:1000])
```

This will be a good deal quicker than looping through the indices and individually multiplying.

Comment: It's important to use languages idiomatically.

Comment: @duffymo what do you mean by that?

Comment: Don't write R as if you were using C.  The proper idiom uses constructs like the one in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should rather use vectorization and some tricks to avoid indexes:

```
with(df, sum(head(col,-3)*tail(col,-3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the `lead` function:

```
sum(df$col * lead(df$col, 3, default = 0))
```